# Move files script assistance

Tags: bash

I'm fairly new to Linux and I'm the learning process. Currently I'm going over the basics of scripting and I'm playing with my first scripts to practice and I was wondering if you could give me a hand in with this one.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.mp4" | while read files2move;
do
        f=$files2move
        mv $f ~/My_stuff        
done
```

I have a Download folder with a bunch of mkv and mp4, but each one is contained on its own folder and instead of moving each file individually to My_stuff I created this to move all the files it finds to My_stuff..

It's working so far but I also want to add a way to delete the directory where the file was after the file is moved, but I have no clue on how to do that.

Could someone point me to the right direction or provide some help on the matter?

...............EDIT..................

Well i did some trial an error and i think i might have come with a solution.  @Kent thanks but my knowledge is way too basic to follow you with your answer.

Anyhow this is what i ended up doing.  If you can tell me of a better way to improve it please let me know

```
#!/bin/bash
root_dir=$PWD
find . -type f -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.mp4" | while read files2move;
do

        f=$files2move
        directory_name=$(dirname "${f}")
        mv "$f" ~/My_stuff
        cd $root_dir
        rm -r "$directory_name"
done
```

Comment: just add this before done rm -rf . *.txt *.mp4 at least this should delete after move in current dir

Comment: I want to delete the folder ...  Lets say i have a file on ~/Downloads/ABC/ABC.mkv  ... i want to move the ABC.mkv to ~/My_stuff and then delete the ABC folder

Answer (score 0):

this one liner works here:

```
 find . -type f -a -regex ".*\.\(mp4\|mkv\)$"|awk -v q='"' -v target="$target"
 '{a=$0;sub(/\/[^/]*$/,"",a);c="mv %s %s && rm -r %s\n"; printf c, q$0q, target, q a q}'|sh
```

remove the ending `|sh` to see generated command, if everything is right, add the `|sh` to execute them.